# Is it possible to use only the HTML 5 application cache for a webapp?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I'm developing a webapp, which should even work if the iphone is offline. I used the HTML5 application cache to implement this feature.

But: can i force the webapp to use only cached elements? Cause if you have a poor internet connection, loading the app is pain, cause it loads all elements from the internet. If i could display cached files (e.g. big images), the loading time can be much faster.

Any ideas?

Comment: And what if there is a cache miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web app will use cached elements unless it detects a change in the cache.manifest file. So as long as you don't update the file (it's bit by bit, so even a comment change will make it appear updated) the web app will continue to use the cached code/images/etc. as long as you explicitly list them in the CACHE section, unless you put them or directories in the NETWORK section.

Comment: Strange. I thought the webapp will always load the files from the internet if there is a connection. Anyway, great news! :) thanks!